# Sort by function, on angular js, clicking header table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm attempting to learn angular. I've been using the default hr schema from Oracle and I'm using a web API to bring back the employee collection and the department collection.

I'm rendering an HTML table to display the employee info. For the department column I have a function that takes the `emp.department_id`, does a lookup on the department collection and returns the department name.

I have headers on the table that when clicked sort the table in ascending or descending.

However I'm struggling with the sort on the department name column since department name is not actually a field on the employee collection. I tried to sort by the function I was using to get the value but I'm not quite getting it.

In my controller I have the following function to get the department name:

```
$scope.getDeptName = function(id){
for (var i=0; < model.departments.length; i++{
   if(model.departments[i].department_id == id){
       return model.departments[i].department_name;
    }}}
```

My table headers:

```
<tr><th><a href="#" ng-click=orderByField='last_name'; reverseSort =! reverseSort>Name</a><th>

<th><a href="#" ng-click=orderByField='getDeptName(department_id)'; reverseSort =! reverseSort>Dept Name</a><th></tr>

<tr> ng-repeat="emp in model.employees |orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort">
```

The sort by Department Name is not working, I'm unsure how to sort by the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The orderByField must be set to *the function* allowing to get the name of the employee. Not to a string containing a call to this function. The correct way is thus

```
ng-click="orderByField = getDeptNameFromEmployee"
```

which, in JS, is equivalent to

```
$scope.orderByField = $scope.getDeptNameFromEmployee;
```

But beware: getDeptNameFromEmployee must take an employee object as parameter, and not an employee ID, for this to work. So it should look like

```
$scope.getDeptNameFromEmployee = function(employee) {
    return $scope.getDeptName(employee.deptId);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Take the quotes off the function call:

```
<a href="#" ng-click=orderByField='getDeptName(department_id)'; reverseSort =! reverseSort>Dept Name</a>
```

should be:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="orderByField=getDeptName(department_id); reverseSort =! reverseSort">Dept Name</a>
```